# Boost python argument error

Tags: c++, python, boost

I just define a function as below and export it to python by using boost.python.

I have a doubt what is the corresponding type of [File* local_conf] in    python.

```
size_t curl_conf(const char* conf_url,FILE *local_conf)
 {
     return 0;
 }


  BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(curl_conf)
 {
     using namespace boost::python;
       def("curl_conf",curl_conf,"get conf");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As quick google search and I found this blog article that seems to exactly answer your question : http://bfroehle.com/2011/10/file-and-boost-python/

You have to write a small wrapper as there is no direct conversion.

An example of the wrapper can be found here : https://gist.github.com/1265889

However, an alternative is to pass a string and open the file on the c++-side. It's up to you.

Comment: Thanks, It needs some work to transfer from fd to FILE ,vice versa .        filepath --fopen()-->FILE*;
   filepath--open()--fd;
   fd--fdopen()-->FILE*;
   fd--readlink(/proc/%getpid()/fd/%fd"))-->filepath;